# Looping through 2 numpy arrays and concatenating them

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

I have two numpy arrays

data_0.shape = (500, 52)   and

data_3.shape = (480, 52)

I am trying to create a new array by concatenating the above two arrays in a special way. So far I have been doing this manually like this.

```
data_train = np.concatenate((data_0[:50],data_3[:50],data_0[50:100],data_3[50:100],data_0[100:150],data_3[100:150],
                        data_0[150:200],data_3[150:200],data_0[200:250],data_3[200:250],data_0[250:300],data_3[250:300],
                        data_0[300:350],data_3[300:350],data_0[350:400],data_3[350:400],data_0[400:450],data_3[400:450],
                        data_0[450:],data_3[450:]))
```

As you can see, I am basically grabbing 50 values each from data_0 and data_3 repeatedly and concatenating them together to get the new array data_train, the shape of which is as follows.

data_train.shape = (980, 52)

This process is extremely time consuming and I am trying to automate this task. This is how my code looks like but I am confused as to how to loop through these 2 arrays simultaneously and also how to concatenate them by grabbing 50 values each from both arrays in an alternating way?

```
j = 0
k = 10
data_train = []

   data_train.append(np.concatenate((data_0[j:k],data_3[j:k])))
   j = j+10
   k = k+10
   data_train = np.array(data_train)
```

How should I initiate the for loop here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) takes any sequence, we can pass a list-comprehension:

```
np.concatenate([arr[i:i+50] for i in range(0, 500, 50) for arr in (data_0, data_3)])
```

---

In English, this says that for a starting index, `i`, that goes from `0`, in steps of `50`, to `500` (not including it so ending at `450`) and an array from: `data_0`, `data_3`, take the slice from this starting index to that index `+50`.

And it yields the following:

```
data_0[0:50]
data_3[0:50]
data_0[50:100]
data_3[50:100]
...
data_0[450:500]
data_3[450:500]
```

Which is what we want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The inner list can be made by a list comprehension

```
collection = sum([data0[50*i: 50*(i+1)], data3[50*i: 50*(i+1)]] for i in range(int(len(train_data)//50)), start=[]]
```

This creates pairs of `[data0, data3]` slices, and makes a list of them using the `sum` function (which, in this case, joins the lists into a bigger list)

Comment: Thanks a lot, much appreciated